# useing flask-socketIO as a Notification Handler (server-client ) connection

Tags: python, flask, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm new to using socketIO and I'm trying to build a notification system using it.

It says on **flask-socketIO** [Official website link](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#sending-messages) That it's possible and ready for it. but for some reason I kept getting error

`AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'namespace'`

pythonApp.py

```
@app.route("/ajaxHandler", methods=['post'])
def ajaxHandler(userSessionId):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        print(f'\n\n >> data: {data}\n\n')
        notify_User({'test':'test1'},userSessionId) # >>>> Notice 1 

    return jsonify({'Ajax': 'completed'})

@socketio.on('notify_User' , namespace='/notifications/')
def notify_User(data,sid):
msg= {"hi": hello}
    emit('notify_User',msg, room=sid) # >>> Notice 2
```

`Notice 1: I could pull userSessionId from database but for the sake of this example i'm pullingit from the user`

`Notice 2 : the error is generated from this line`

socket_Io.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

   // Connect to websocket
   var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

   var socket = io();

    socket.on("notify_User",(data) => {

        console.log(`i got this : ${data}`)
    });
```

I kept searching the error everywhere, but I couldn't find any answer that could help in my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `notify_User()` is defined as a Socket.IO event handler. This function will automatically run when the client emits the `notify_User` event.

You are calling this function directly in your `ajaxHandler()` view function. This is not the correct usage, a Socket.IO event handler is not supposed to be called from the server, the client triggers this function when it emits the Socket.IO event.

If you want to emit an event to the client from the `ajaxHandler()` route, then use the `emit()` function to do so. Because this is an HTTP route and not a Socket.IO event, you will need to provide some information that is not available outside of the Socket.IO connection. For that reason the `namespace` and `sid` arguments are required when using `emit()` outside of a Socket.IO handler.